# Using n inside calc

Tags: css, css-calc

can I use the n variable inside a calc expression?

For example:

```
.child:nth-child(n) {
   margin-left: calc(n * 46px);
}
```

My Code:

```
<div class="share-buttons">
  <div class="share-button-main"></div>
  <div class="share-button share-facebook">
    <img src="facebook.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="share-button share-whatsapp">
    <img src="whatsapp.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="share-button share-email">
    <img src="email.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="share-button share-sms">
    <img src="sms.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (Sass):

```
.share-buttons {
  position: relative;
    display: flex;

  .share-button-main {
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    content: url('share-menu-share-closed.png')
  }

  .share-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &.open {
    .share-button-main {
      content: url('share-menu-share-opened.png')
    }
    .share-button {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .share-facebook {
      left: 56px;
    }

    .share-whatsapp {
      left: 112px;
    }

    .share-email {
      left: 168px;
    }

    .share-sms {
      left: 224px;
    }
  }

    img {
        width: 46px;
        height: 46px;
    }
}
```

Javascript (JQuery):

```
$('.share-button-main').click(function() {
  $('.share-buttons').toggleClass('open');
});
```

I'm basically trying to acheive a dynamic opening effect to the menu so if I add or remove elements it'll still work (and not like now when I set each div's left separately).

Comment: well if you're using sass already why not create a mixin or function for this?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Seems to me all you are asking is to have these elements in a row...you don't need positioning for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, as mentioned by @SLaks. But this can be solved by placing each next element inside the previous one.

See with divs:

```css
div {
  margin-left: 46px
}
```

```html
<div>test
  <div>test
    <div>test
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, use jQuery.

```js
var margin=0;
$("div").each(function(){
  $(this).css("margin-left",margin+=46)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: My actual elements are absolute divs.

Comment: @Daniel added another solution.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you may be after, but you can achieve a similar effect with scss if you know the number of elements. Just bear in mind that this will generate a lot of css:

```
@for $i from 1 through 7 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      margin-left: calc(#{$i} * 46px);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

No; you can't do that.

The `counter` feature can *almost* do that, except that it can't be used with `calc()` either.

Comment: So is there any way I can do such thing? give an element left-margin based on it's previous sibling left-margin?